# Trying to set Json Ignore for some of the field in class

Tags: java, annotations, jackson, json

Here I am trying to convert class into json string. During conversion, for one field, I want @JsonIgnore to be set

Campaign class consists of:

```
int campaignId;
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
```

I am currently doing it this way

```
String data = JacksonObjectMapper.INSTANCE.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Campaign);
```

I want to use it via objects only not via annotations as I am doing it conditionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Gson for it. It has some internal functions to deal with elements and objects.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(object);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
jsonObject.remove("endDate");
```